# Can I change javascript draw function to an image?

Tags: javascript, png, draw

I found a gamecode on github [https://github.com/maryrosecook/retro-games] today. I want to edit it and use png images instead of the draw function, is there anyway I can do it?
Thank you.

```
  BodyBlock.prototype = {
    draw: function(screen) {
      drawRect(screen, this, "black");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawRect() was custom, from scratch function.

```
var drawRect = function(screen, body, color) {
  screen.fillStyle = color;
  screen.fillRect();
};
```

What you are looking for is standard javascript canvas Method.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp

Tutorial : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/